# Using docker-engine unable to access containers (inside WSL2) from host network

Tags: docker, networking

Here is the scenario, I was using Docker Desktop with wsl backed engine and whenever I used to run a container inside my wsl for example:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 somecontainer
```

It was used to be accessible from my Windows host machine network using domain-name of my machine and localhost as well like

```
localhost/coolstuff.html
mypcname/coolstuff.html
```

and doing netstat showed an entry like

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:80         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       19658
```

Now when I have uninstalled Docker Desktop and only using Docker engine, when I do all of the above I am able to access my container inside WSL using `localhost` but over the network I am not able to access my container using domain-name of my machine. Also netstat entry now shows

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:80         127.0.0.1:0              LISTENING       18236
```

I understand that with Docker Desktop the ports were being published using `com.docker.backend.exe` service.

Question is how can I achieve same behavior by only using Docker engine.

I am using a custom Docker network for inter-docker-services communication.